# Subclass from the subclass of UIViewController with Storyboard doesn't work as except

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers, one subclass **`UIViewController`**

```
class MGStatusViewController: UIViewController
```

with storyboard identifier "**`MGStatusViewController`**".(With some `UIButton`s)

And the other subclass `**MGStatusViewController**`

```
class MGStatusDetailViewController: MGStatusViewController
```

with storyboard identifier **`MGStatusDetailViewController`**

When i use it like this:

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MGStatusDetailViewController") as? MGStatusDetailViewController
```

There's no controllers(the `UIButton`s) from MGStatusViewController's storyboad file.

How should i achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: I used ContainerView to make this, but as @NickCatib descriped inherit from view controllers, use them  as an abstract, i think it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inherit your custom view controller - in this example `MGStatusViewController` you inherit code behind and logic. You can connect your outlets for `MGStatusDetailViewController` with `MGStatusViewController`. And that is it. You can't inherit UIView controls from the storyboard and expect them to show.

What you can do is to create `MGStatusDetailViewController` take the view from it and add it to the `MGStatusViewController`. Or, you can create embed control and embed `MGStatusDetailViewController` in `MGStatusViewController`. This way you will have all the controls from storyboard and will present your `MGStatusDetailViewController`

In short, inheritance does not take Views from storyboard, only code from that view controller.

Furthermore, when you inherit from view controllers, you use them as an abstract. You create some logic for that will be used on others view controllers, but you don't create actual UI.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use "MGStatusDetailViewController" story board identifier if you have set identifier as "MGStatusViewController"

Storybord ID and class are diferent thing.

You may try with this -

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MGStatusViewController") as? MGStatusDetailViewController
```